# dynamically inserting content into iframe - jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

when I have a static page with an iframe the jquery is working properly. However, if I dynamically generate the exact same html, jquery is not. If I inspect the element in chrome and copy the dynamically generated iframe contents and save it as a static page, it works.

**Static & jQuery works**:

*test.html:*

```
...
<iframe name="result" sandbox="allow-popups allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-modals" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="/iFrame" width="100%" height="900px"></iframe>
...
```

*iFrame.html:*

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">.test { display:inline-flex; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px; background-color:rgb(50,100,230); color:white;  justify-content:center; align-items:center; font-size:20pt; font-weight:lighter; font-family: sans-serif }</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
      $(document).ready(function() {$('.test').text('hello');});
      //]]>
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">.iFrameStyle: { margin:10px; }</style>
  </head>
  <body class="iFrameStyle">
    <div class="test">test</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

*result*:
[image]

**Dynamically generating this iFrame - jQuery fails to load**

*chrome inspector of iframe*

```
   <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js">               
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
          .test { display:inline-flex; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px; background-color:rgb(50,100,230); color:white;  justify-content:center; align-items:center; font-size:20pt; font-weight:lighter; font-family: sans-serif }
         </style>
         <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
           $(document).ready(function() { 
              $('.test').text('hello');
           });
    //]]>
    </script>
   <style type="text/css">.iFrameStyle: { margin:10px; }</style>
   </head>
    <body class="iFrameStyle"><div class="test">test</div></body></html>
```

*result* (should be hello)

*how the iframe content is dynamically being generated:*

```
function showPreview() {
    var button = $('.createComponentPreview');
    var update = $('.updateComponentPreview');
    update.fadeIn();
    //set the name above the card
    var name = $('.componentName').val();
    if (name === '') {
      name = $('.componentTempName').text();
    }
    $('.componentNameVal').text(name);

    //set the iframe contents
    var sandbox = $('.sandboxed');
    var html = $('textarea[name="html"]').val();
    var css = $('textarea[name="css"]').val();
    var js = $('textarea[name="js"]').val();

    //remove any previous content
    var head = sandbox.contents().find('head');
    var body = sandbox.contents().find('body');
    head.empty();
    body.empty();

    //insert
    var htmlContainer = document.createElement('div');
    var cssContainer = document.createElement('style');
    var jsContainer = document.createElement('script');
    jsContainer.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    cssContainer.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    var iFrameStyle = $(cssContainer).clone();
    $(head).append(cssContainer);
    $(head).append(jsContainer);
    $(html).append(htmlContainer);
    $(cssContainer).text('\n\t'+css+'\n');
    $(head).append(iFrameStyle);
    iFrameStyle.append('.iFrameStyle: { margin:10px; }');

    //append any environment scripts
    for (var i in componentOptions) {
      if (componentOptions[i] == 'jquery') {
        head.prepend('<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>');
        js = '$(document).ready(function() {'+js+'});';
      }
      else if (componentOptions[i] == 'react') {
        head.prepend('<script type="text/javascript" src="react-dom.min.js"></script>');
        head.prepend('<script type="text/javascript" src="react.min.js"></script>');
      }
      else if (componentOptions[i] == 'noMargin') {
        iFrameStyle.append('.iFrameStyle { margin:0px; }');
      }
      else if (componentOptions[i] == 'alignCenter') {
        iFrameStyle.append('.iFrameStyle { display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center }');
      }
    }
    body.removeAttr('marginwidth').removeAttr('marginheight');
    body.addClass('iFrameStyle');
    body.prepend(html);
    $(jsContainer).text('//<![CDATA[\n'+js+'\n//]]>\n');

    sandbox.css('min-height', '300px');
    sandbox.css('width', '100%');
    var card = $('.contentContainer.expandable').fadeIn();


    button.text('Close Preview');
    button.attr('previewMode', 'true');
  }
```

*the error message I am getting:*

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

and the link in chrome's developer console to this error shows:

```
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {$('.test').text('hello');});
//]]>
```

both the working static and dynamic non-working iframes both contain the exact same url for jquery, and I am not getting a 404 error.

I'm stuck on this so any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience working with iframes and i think you are trying to abuse the purpose of iframes by doing this. Iframes are designed in order to show content from third party site on your site.

In this case, it means that you are trying to load content dynamically using jQuery. the error message you see means jQuery is not loaded. You didnt specify where exactly your "showPreview()" is being defined and called BUT(!) did you notice that you are using a mix of vanilla JS and jquery in this function ?

```
function showPreview() {
    var button = $('.createComponentPreview');
    var update = $('.updateComponentPreview');
```

This in turn while running the script changes to:

```
function showPreview() {
    var button, update;
    button = $('.createComponentPreview');
    update = $('.updateComponentPreview');
```

Now the browser "sees" a dollar sign and complains that it doesnt know what it means. which is basically because at that time(!) you dont have jquery added to the function.

In your case you are trying to find an element by its class name. change this to vanilla JS instead

```
function returnFirstElementOfClass(className) {
   var matchingElements = getElementsByClassName(document, className),
   return elements[0];
}
```

Then change your code to:

```
function showPreview() {
    var button, update;
    button = returnFirstElementOfClass('createComponentPreview');
    update = returnFirstElementOfClass('updateComponentPreview');
```

You have to repeat this untill u have jquery loaded, and then use delegated events. in my eyes i see a simpler solution. Dont use iframe for this and instead use iframe for their intended purpose. instead load the content into a container, that way you have access to all the scripts which are already loaded in the DOM. use iframe SRC attribute to control what page to load and when.

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution

```
$('#myIframe').attr("src", "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(data))
```

where data is a full html page like this
`data = '<html><body><h1>Test</h1></body></html>'`;